# An open connected set $A$ is the disjoint union of open rectangles if and only if $A$ is itself an open rectangle.

Tags: real-analysis

An open connected set $A$ is the disjoint union of open rectangles if and only if $A$ is itself an open rectangle.

proof: Recall that an open disc in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not the disjoint union of open rectangles.

By contradiction, suppose $A$ is not an open rectangle. So $A$ has at least two rectangles $A = R_1 \cap R_2.$
These rectangles are not disjoint, so we have a contradiction.
So A must be an open rectangle.

Conversely, let A be an open rectangle.

Can someone please help me?
Thank you!

Comment: Were does your "proof" use the assumption that $A$ is connected? How do you get $A=R_1\cap R_2$? What definition of "connected": are you using? From where are we supposed to "recall" that an open disc is not the disjoint union of open rectangles; is that a theorem in your book? Do you mind telling us what book you are using?

Comment: I am using a theorem that every open set in $\mathbb{R}$ is the disjoint union of open intervals. and that it's false for $\mathbb{R}^d$ for $d >= 2$.

Comment: I am using princeton lectures notes in analysis by Stein and Shakarchi

Comment: Your last sentence is "Conversely, let $A$ be an open rectangle...".  Is this the part you're not sure about?  Any set is a disjoint union of one set, namely itself.

Comment: During the contradiction part of your proof. Where do you get that A is the intersection of two rectangles? The open disc is definitely not the intersection of two rectangles, for example

Answer (score 1):

I think this:

1) $(H_1)$ $\Omega$ is an open connected rectangle.
$(T_1)$ $\Omega=\cup_{i=1}^{n}R_i$ where $R_i \cap R_j=\emptyset$ for $i\neq j$ and $R_i$ are open rectangles.

prove:

note we can take $R_1=\Omega$ and $R_i=\emptyset \ \  \forall i \geq 2$.

2) $(H_2)$ $\Omega$ is open connected and $\Omega=\cup_{i=1}^{n}R_i$ where $R_i \cap R_j=\emptyset$ for $i\neq j$ and $R_i$ are open rectangles.

$(T_2)$ $\Omega$ is a rectangle.

prove:

by $H_2$ we can take $\Omega=R_1 \cup \left( \cup_{i=2}^n R_i\right)$ where $R_1 \cap \left( \cup_{i=2}^n R_i\right)=\emptyset$ as $\Omega$ is connected there are two options:

(i) $R_1=\Omega$ and $\left( \cup_{i=2}^n R_i\right)=\emptyset$

(ii) $R_1=\emptyset$ and $\left( \cup_{i=2}^n R_i\right)=\Omega$

note that in (i) we have $(T_2)$ as $R_1=\Omega$ and in (ii) we can separate as before so we can conclude  $\exists k \in \left\lbrace 2,3, \ldots n \right\rbrace$ such that $R_k=\Omega$ and $R_i=\emptyset \ \forall i\neq k$.